# 403 Forbidden при попытке подключить Yandex Maps

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой - при попытке подключить Yandex Maps через `$('head').append('<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>');` в консоли появляется ошибка `GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&_=1530952276760 403 (Forbidden)`
С чем это может быть связано? При подключении на codepen.io подобных ошибок не возникает.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка **403 Forbidden** означает, что для **Вашего сайта** или **IP** адреса **запрещен** доступ к API Яндекс.Карты. Вам нужно обратиться в тех.поддержку Яндекса.